# Split words and creating new files with different names(python)

Tags: python, parsing, split

**I need to write a program like this:**
Write a program that reads a file .picasa.ini and copies pictures in new files, whose names are the same as identification numbers of person on these pictures (eg. 8ff985a43603dbf8.jpg). If there are more person on the picture it makes more copies. If a person is on more pictures, later override earlier copies of pictures; if a person 8ff985a43603dbf8 may appear in more pictures, only one file with this name will exist. You must presume that we have a simple file .picasa.ini.

**I have an .ini, that consists:**

```
[img_8538.jpg]
faces=rect64(4ac022d1820c8624),**d5a2d2f6f0d7ccbc**
backuphash=46512

[img_8551.jpg]
faces=rect64(acb64583d1eb84cb),**2623af3d8cb8e040**;rect64(58bf441388df9592),**d85d127e5c45cdc2**
backuphash=8108
...
```

Is this a good way to start this program?

```
for line in open('C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\podatki-picasa\.picasa.ini'):
    if line.startswith('faces'):
        line.split() # what must I do here to split the bolded words?
```

Is there a better way to do this? Remember the .jpg file must be created with a new name, so I think I should link the current .jpg file with the bolded one.

Comment: You need to explain better what the data format is for each line of the shown `picasa.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html).  Then you will have to split each value by hand, as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Your lines don't start with 'faces', so your second line won't work the way you want it to. Depending on how the rest of the file looks, you might only need to check whether the line is empty or not at that point.
2. To get the information you need, first split at ',' and work from there

Try at a solution: The elements you need seem to always have a ',' before them, so you can start by splitting at the ',' sign and taking everything from the 1-index elemnt onwards [1::] . Then if what I am thinking is correct, you split those elements twice again: at the ";" and take the 0-index element of that and at that " ", again taking the 0-index element.

```
for line in open('thingy.ini'):
if line != "\n":
    personelements = line.split(",")[1::]
    for person in personelements:
        personstring = person.split(";")[0].split(" ")[0]
        print personstring
```

works for me to get:

d5a2d2f6f0d7ccbc

2623af3d8cb8e040

d85d127e5c45cdc2

Answer (score 0):

```
import ConfigParser
import string
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\podatki-picasa\.picasa.ini')
imgs = []
for item in config.sections():
    imgs.append(config.get(item, 'faces'))
```

This is still work in progress. Just want to ask if it's correct.

edit:
Still don't know hot to split the bolded words out of there. This split function really is a pain for me.